# lob out something

Tags: meaning

This is from [a webpage](https://www.tallahassee.com/story/life/family/2019/01/15/maglab-couple-spreads-science-cheer-curious-kids/2575383002/).

> At a recent Science Night about magnetism, she got things started by
> **lobbing out** a question.
>
> “What’s a magnet?”
>
> Kids returned the volley with a flurry of ideas.
>
> “Something that sticks to a refrigerator.”

I wonder what 'lob out something' means.

Given the definition of verb 'lob' in [a dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lob), my sense is that 'lob out' means 'throw a question or something of that sort to everyone'.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "lob" = "throw (or hit a ball), in a high arc". It is used quite formally in games like tennis, and informally to mean throw without careful aim, so that anyone could catch it.

Metaphorically, to "lob (out) a question" means to ask a question (to a group of people, here a class of children) without directing it at an individual.

Comment: Thank you very much.